# Loop through .txt to create two delimiters depending on data index

Tags: python, database, loops, delimiter

So I have a number of files (1000ish) each with 90k plus lines, where the data was recorded in the incorrect format and I am trying to make reformat the txt files.

The data currently looks like this:

9/3/2021 00 00 00 -0.18  -2.40 -2.40
9/3/2021 00 00 01 -0.18  -2.40 -2.40
9/3/2021 00 00 02 -0.18  -2.40 -2.40
9/3/2021 00 00 03 -0.17  -2.40 -2.40
.....

However, it should look like

9/3/2021,00:00:00,-0.18, , ,-2.40,-2.40
9/3/2021,00:00:01,-0.18, , ,-2.40,-2.40
9/3/2021,00:00:02,-0.18, , ,-2.40,-2.40
9/3/2021,00:00:03,-0.17, , ,-2.40,-2.40
....

I have managed to go through everything and add a " , " with

```py
input = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/ssdat/SegY TidalCorrection 03092021.txt"))
content = input.read()
content = content.replace(" ", ",")
print(content)
```

resulting in an output of:
9/3/2021,17,22,47,0.20,1511.10,-2.12,-2.29
9/3/2021,17,22,48,0.01,1511.10,-2.29,-2.29
9/3/2021,17,22,49,-0.17,1511.05,-2.41,-2.29
9/3/2021,17,22,50,-0.14,1511.02,-2.34,-2.30

So I guess my question is how can I loop through everything to make two new delimiters?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output? It's not clear to me what you mean by "two new delimiters".

Comment: Who should consume the data? Cant the consumer change his logic from delimiter A to delimiter B ?

Comment: @danoscarmike Howdy, so basically the data looks like:   9/3/2021 00 00 00 -0.18 -2.40 -2.40
However it should look like 9/3/2021, 00:00:00, -0.18, , , -2.40, -2.40
In the second case, it is a date, time( which has ':' as the delimiter each second ) and then returning back to a ' , ' for the rest of that row

Comment: @balderman Heya, the consumer is an application that will use the values to apply corrections to the difference in tidal height, if it's not in the right formation it simply won't accept the data. I have already changed the original application that created the txt file to no longer make this issue, but I have a lot of data that be manually changed, hence looking for a better solution with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @bret-hogg's answer. But if you're only interested in recreating a simple string on each line then the following will work:

```py
import os


with open("your_old_file.txt", "r") as text_file, open("your_new_file.txt", "w") as csv_file:
    for line in text_file:
        fields = line.split(" ")
        date = fields[0]
        time = fields[1] + ":" + fields[2] + ":" + fields[3]
        replacement_row = f"{date},{time},{fields[4]},,,{fields[5]},{fields[6]}"
        csv_file.write(replacement_row)
```

Comment: Heya! This totally worked, however to make the data clean had to add a \n to the replacement_tow at the end. Made new rows :)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to iterate through the text file line by line and then character by character.  Assuming you already know how your data should be formatted, you could then look for spaces and replace them with the desired delimiter.